# How to focus cursor on a stripe input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

I am trying to add in a credit card form with Stripe Elements (https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#other-methods).

Normally I would focus on an element by doing:

```
$('input[type="tel"]').focus()
```

However, this doesn't work with the Stripe credit card input. However, the following does work:

```
$('input[type="tel"]').value='asdf'
```

So it is grabbing the correct item. How would I focus the cursor on the input item? It seems like it may be inside an iframe, even though I can write a value to it in jquery/javascript.

Comment: Maybe simulate a click?

Comment: @JBDouble05 it seems like it may be in an iframe? Also, how would a click be simulated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `focus()` [method](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#other-methods) on the element that you created and not the div itself.

For example you can have a button that gives focus to the CVC element (assuming split fields) by doing

```
document.getElementById('give-focus').addEventListener('click', function () {
  cardCvcElement.focus();
});
```

You can see this in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/4c72oyap/

Comment: how would I do that on page load though? The point of the above would be to select the field as soon as it's loaded. In the above, you actually have to click something (why wouldn't the user just click the form input instead?).

Answer (score 11):

The element needs to be fully initialized before you can call `focus()`. Ensure the element is ready with a simple event handler:

```
element.on('ready', () => {
  element.focus()
})
```

Comment: Yes, i.e. `const paymentElement = elements.create('payment'); paymentElement.mount('#payment-element'); paymentElement.on('ready', (e) => paymentElement.focus());`

Answer (score 2):

You can trigger the focus method after your element created when it's ready

```
Example: 
var cardElement = elements.create('cardNumber', { showIcon: true, style: style, classes: elementClasses });
cardElement.mount('#card-element');
cardElement.on('ready', (e) => cardElement.focus());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 let elements = stripe.elements();    
let cardCvcElement = elements.create("cardCvc");
cardCvcElement.mount("#card-cvc-element");

    let cvc = document.querySelector("#card-cvc-element");
    cardCvcElement.addEventListener("blur", () => {
      cvc.style.removeProperty("border");
    });
    cardCvcElement.addEventListener("focus", () => {

        cvc.style.setProperty("border-color","red");
      }
    });
```

Comment: Some explanation accompanying your answer would be pretty helpful. The code may be straightforward enough, but we would like to know why you think this is a solution.

Comment: Indeed we can't act directly on the stripe input. We have to go through the stripe element components.https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart#setup

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Stripe-react-js SDK, here is how to focus:

```
<CardElement
  options={CARD_ELEMENT_OPTIONS}
  onReady={(e) => e.focus()}
/>
```

Link to official docs https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react#element-components